# attempt to free memory causes error

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have declared the following struct:

```
typedef struct _RECOGNITIONRESULT {
        int begin_time_ms, end_time_ms;
        char* word;
} RECOGNITIONRESULT;
```

There is a method that creates an array of RECOGNITIONRESULT and fills it (for test purposes only):

```
void test_realloc(RECOGNITIONRESULT** p, int count){
    int i;
    *p = (RECOGNITIONRESULT *)realloc(*p, count * sizeof(RECOGNITIONRESULT));
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
        (*p)[i].begin_time_ms = 2*i;
        (*p)[i].end_time_ms = 2*i+1;
        (*p)[i].word=(char *) malloc ( (strlen("hello"+1) * sizeof(char ) ));
        strcpy((*p)[i].word,"hello");
    }
}
```

The method to free memory is:

```
void free_realloc(RECOGNITIONRESULT* p, int count){
    int i = 0;
    if(p != NULL){
        if (count > 0){
            for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
                free(p[i].word);      //THE PROBLEM IS HERE.
            }
        }
        free(p);
    }
}
```

The main method calls those methods like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int count = 10;
    RECOGNITIONRESULT *p = NULL;
    test_realloc(&p,count);
    free_realloc(p,count);
    return 0;
}
```

Then if I try to free the memory allocated for "word", I get the following error:

HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after normal block (#63) at 0x003D31D8.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

Using the debugger I've discovered that the crash occurs when calling free(p[i].word);

What am I doing wrong? How can I free he memory for the strings?

Comment: Use `valgrind` http://valgrind.org/ or some similar memory leakage detector. Learn to use it for your future bugs!

Comment: It's not a leak what I am looking for, is an error calling to the free method. Is valgrind suitable for anything else than finding memory leaks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your allocation of memory for `word`. `strlen("hello"+1)` should be `strlen("hello")+1`.

Comment: the funny thing is that strlen("hello"+1) is actually the same as writing strlen("hello")-1.

Comment: OMG. That's too embarrassing. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to allocate a whole array of structures in one strike

```
RECOGNITIONRESULT **p;
*p = (RECOGNITIONRESULT *)realloc(*p, count * sizeof(RECOGNITIONRESULT));
```

you can free them in one call to free() as well :

```
void free_realloc(RECOGNITIONRESULT *p, int count){
        free(p);
}
```

And the `strlen("hello"+1)` is also wrong, as detected by Chowlett.

Comment: will that also free all the memory allocated for the inner strings?

Comment: What about the `malloc()` for the `word` member of each `struct`?

Comment: My answer is actually correct. The OP confuses himself by using the name "p" for both *p and **p. And you are right about the word-member. But in his code that would have leaked also (if it even compled)Oops no. I was wrong. sorry...

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. Mainly by the baraoque style of your program. Maybe as a service I should tidy it up a bit to show my point?

Comment: I know the code is a bit complicated to perform such a simple thing, but it's just a sample code to show what I was trying to do in a much more complex program. Passing the pointer and reallocating is something I need to do since the size of the result will depend on results provided by third party libraries. Anyway, trying to help is always much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you noticed that the realloc() actually introduces a memory leak if the argument is not NULL?. If it is always NULL: why not use malloc or calloc instead, and avoid the risk of leaking (once the code decides to actually call it with a nonNULL pointer) ?